# R - Creating a new column within a data frame when two or more columns are a match in a row

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I'm currently stuck on a part of my code that feels intuitive but I can't figure a way to do it. I have a very big data frame (nrows = 34036, ncol = 43) in which I want to create a continuous sequence of the variables where the value of the row is 1 (without having multiple columns with 1). It consists of only zeros and ones similar to the following:

```
A B C D
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1
```

I was able to remove the zeroes using:

```
#find the sum of each row
placeholderData <- transform(placeholderData, sum=rowSums(placeholderData)) 
placeholderData <- placeholderData[!(placeholderData$sum <= 0),]
```

And the data frame now looks like:

```
A B C D sum
1 0 0 0  1
0 0 0 1  1
0 0 0 1  1
1 0 1 0  2
1 0 1 0  2
0 1 0 0  1
0 1 0 0  1
1 0 0 1  2
```

My main problem comes when there are two or more 1's in a row. To try to solve this, I used the following code to identify the columns that have a sum of 2 or more:

```
placeholderData$Matches <- lapply(apply(placeholderData == 1, 1, which), names)
```

Which added the following column to the data frame:

```
A B C D sum   Matches
1 0 0 0  1      A
0 0 0 1  1      D
0 0 0 1  1      D
1 0 1 0  2  c("A","C")
1 0 1 0  2  c("A","C")
0 1 0 0  1      B
0 1 0 0  1      B
1 0 0 1  2  c("A", "D")
```

I added the Matches column as an approach to solve the problem, but I'm not sure how would I do it without using a lot of logical operators (I don't know what columns have matches or not). What I would like to do is to aggregate the rows that have more than (or equal to) two 1's into a new column, to be able to have a data frame like this:

```
A B C D AC AD sum   Matches
1 0 0 0 0  0  1      A
0 0 0 1 0  0  1      D
0 0 0 1 0  0  1      D
0 0 0 0 1  0  1  c("A","C")
0 0 0 0 1  0  1  c("A","C")
0 1 0 0 0  0  1      B
0 1 0 0 0  0  1      B
0 0 0 0 0  1  1  c("A", "D")
```

Then, I would be able to use my code as normal (It works just fine when there are no repeated values in rows). I tried searching to find similar questions, but I'm not sure if I was even asking the right question. I was wondering if anyone could provide some help or some ideas that I could try.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a lot like making dummy variables, so I would use the `model.matrix` function commonly used for dummy variables (one-hot encoding):

```
m = read.table(header = T, text = "A B C D
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 1")

m = m[rowSums(m) > 0, ]
d = factor(sapply(apply(m == 1, 1, which), function(x) paste(names(m)[x], collapse = "")))
result = data.frame(model.matrix(~ d + 0))
names(result) = levels(d)
#   A AC AD B D
# 1 1  0  0 0 0
# 2 0  0  0 0 1
# 3 0  0  0 0 1
# 4 0  1  0 0 0
# 5 0  1  0 0 0
# 6 0  0  0 1 0
# 7 0  0  0 1 0
# 8 0  0  1 0 0
```

Comment: I'm astonished, such an elegant answer. It even made parts of my code useless. Gregor, thank you so much.